# Scheduling GPU in Kubernetes v1.13.1

Tags: kubernetes

I’m trying to scheduling GPU in Kubernetes v1.13.1 and I followed the guide in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#deploying-nvidia-gpu-device-plugin

But the gpu resources doesn't show up when I run 
`kubectl get nodes -o yaml`,  according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812783/scheduling-gpus-in-kubernetes-1-10), I checked the Nvidia gpu device plugin.

I run:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/v1.11/nvidia-device-plugin.yml
```

several times and the result is

```
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/v1.11/nvidia-device-plugin.yml": daemonsets.extensions "nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset" already exists
```

It seems that I have installed the NVIDIA Device Plugin? But the result of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` is

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-node-qdhvd                  2/2     Running   0          65m
kube-system   coredns-78d4cf999f-fk4wl           1/1     Running   0          68m
kube-system   coredns-78d4cf999f-zgfvl           1/1     Running   0          68m
kube-system   etcd-liuqin01                      1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-liuqin01            1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-liuqin01   1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   kube-proxy-l8p9p                   1/1     Running   0          68m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-liuqin01            1/1     Running   0          67m
```

When I run `kubectl describe node`, gpu is not in the the allocatable resource

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (9 in total)
Namespace                  Name                                    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
---------                  ----                                    ----------- -  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
kube-system                calico-node-qdhvd                       250m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
kube-system                coredns-78d4cf999f-fk4wl                100m (0%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     19h
kube-system                coredns-78d4cf999f-zgfvl                100m (0%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     19h
kube-system                etcd-liuqin01                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         19h
kube-system                kube-apiserver-liuqin01                 250m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         19h
kube-system                kube-controller-manager-liuqin01        200m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         19h
kube-system                kube-proxy-l8p9p                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         19h
kube-system                kube-scheduler-liuqin01                 100m (0%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         19h
kube-system                nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-p78wz    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         26m
Allocated resources:
(Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
Resource           Requests    Limits
--------           --------    ------
cpu                1 (8%)      0 (0%)
memory             140Mi (0%)  340Mi (2%)
ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
```

Comment: "Is the Device Plugin installed successfully?" is a separate question from "why don't I see nvidia pods"; the answer to the pods question is because [the taints and tolerations](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.0/roles/kubernetes-apps/container_engine_accelerator/nvidia_gpu/templates/nvidia-driver-install-daemonset.yml.j2#L36-L39) are not lined up. If you asked `kubectl get ds --all-namespaces` you'd see your nvidia driver ones, but at a count of 0

Comment: That said, I also had a miserable time getting the kubernetes provided nvidia driver process to work because of custom AWS kernels in the ubuntu AMIs; using [nvidia's process](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker#ubuntu-140416041804-debian-jessiestretch) went much smoother

Comment: Yes, the pod doesn't show up because I didn't run `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`. After I run this command, I can see the nvidia device plugin pod running. But the gpu resources are still not visible, I added details above.

Comment: I found the answer! I didn't reload the daemon and restart docker after configuring the default runtime of docker.

Comment: Could you please explain with more details how you've solved it in the answer section?

Comment: @VAS After installing nvidia-docker2, the default runtime of docker should be modified to nvidia docker as https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#preparing-your-gpu-nodes. After modifying the /etc/docker/daemon.json, you need to restart docker so that the configuration works.

Comment: Thanks! I'll put your explanation as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [lianyouCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5850603/lianyoucat) mentioned in the comments:

> After installing nvidia-docker2, the default runtime of docker should be modified to nvidia docker as [github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#preparing-your-gpu-nodes](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#preparing-your-gpu-nodes).
>
> After modifying the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, you need to restart docker so that the configuration works.